# Unable to deploy Solidity contract to Rinkeby network (Invalid asm.js: Invalid member of stdlib)

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, ethereum, solidity

I've been learning Solidity using [this course](https://www.udemy.com/share/1013FsAEcfclhRQXQ=/) by Stephen Grider and it's been going well until now, where I am trying to deploy [my code](https://github.com/zbaskin/eth-inbox) to the Rinkeby test network.

For reference, I am using Node version 11.15.0 with npm version 6.7.0 with these dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ganache-cli": "^6.4.3",
    "mocha": "^6.1.4",
    "nan": "^2.14.0",
    "scrypt": "^6.0.3",
    "solc": "^0.4.25",
    "truffle": "^4.1.15",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "0.0.4",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.35" }
```

I have spent hours switching between versions of Node.js, npm, and all sorts of combinations of the dependencies, from the most current versions to the versions specified in the course. While I am getting a multitude of issues, the most prominent two seem to be

```
(node:32436) V8: C:\Desktop\solidity\inbox\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:3 Invalid asm.js: Invalid member of stdlib
```

and

```
C:\Desktop\solidity\inbox\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:1
var Module;if(!Module)Module=(typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:null)||{};var moduleOverrides={};for(var key in Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key)){moduleOverrides[key]=Module[key]}}var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof window==="object";var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=typeof importScripts==="function";var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=typeof process==="object"&&typeof require==="function"&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE){if(!Module["print"])Module["print"]=function print(x){process["stdout"].write(x+"\n")};if(!Module["printErr"])Module["printErr"]=function printErr(x){process["stderr"].write(x+"\n")};var nodeFS=require("fs");var nodePath=require("path");Module["read"]=function read(filename,binary){filename=nodePath["normalize"](filename);var ret=nodeFS["readFileSync"](filename);if(!ret&&filename!=nodePath["resolve"](filename)){filename=path.joi

Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node rinkeby.infura.io/v3/acb10732334e4450ba7dc55e618eb70a.
    at Object.InvalidConnection (C:\Desktop\solidity\inbox\node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\errors.js:28:16)
    at HttpProvider.sendAsync (C:\Desktop\solidity\inbox\node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\httpprovider.js:129:25)
    at Web3Subprovider.handleRequest (C:\Desktop\solidity\inbox\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\subproviders\web3.js:13:17)
    at next (C:\Desktop\solidity\inbox\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\index.js:95:18)
    at FilterSubprovider.handleRequest (C:\Desktop\solidity\inbox\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\subproviders\filters.js:87:7)
    at next (C:\Desktop\solidity\inbox\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\index.js:95:18)
    at HookedWalletSubprovider.handleRequest (C:\Desktop\solidity\inbox\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\subproviders\hooked-wallet.js:109:7)
    at next (C:\Desktop\solidity\inbox\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\index.js:95:18)
    at Web3ProviderEngine._handleAsync (C:\Desktop\solidity\inbox\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\index.js:82:3)
    at Web3ProviderEngine._fetchBlock (C:\Desktop\solidity\inbox\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\index.js:191:8)
    at Web3ProviderEngine._fetchLatestBlock (C:\Desktop\solidity\inbox\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\index.js:167:8)
    at Web3ProviderEngine._startPolling (C:\Desktop\solidity\inbox\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\index.js:144:8)
    at Web3ProviderEngine.start (C:\Desktop\solidity\inbox\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\index.js:38:8)
    at new HDWalletProvider (C:\Desktop\solidity\inbox\node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\index.js:46:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Desktop\solidity\inbox\deploy.js:6:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
```

My question would be are there any fixes for either of these issues based on my code, or is there a simpler way to deploy to the blockchain? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node rinkeby.infura.io/v3/acb10732334e4450ba7dc55e618eb70a.`

You probably meant `https://rinkeby.infura.io/...` (You're missing the `https://`.)

Comment: That did the trick, thank you, I can't believe I didn't notice that. I'm still getting the invalid asm.js error, but it doesn't seem to affect the program because my program is returning a valid hash.

Comment: Were you able to solve the invalid asm.js error? What was the fix?

Answer (score 0):

I am following the same tutorial as the OP. If you are using `node` v14.15.4 and `npm` v6.14.10, I would like to confirm that the following *package.json* solved the issue:

```
{
  "name": "inbox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ganache-cli": "^6.4.3",
    "mocha": "^6.1.4",
    "solc": "^0.4.25",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "0.0.4",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.35"
  }
}
```

Then rebuild your dependencies by deleting your `node_modules` of your project, then run

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with the version of the relevant library file, please run the following command.

`npm install solc`

My `npm` version is `7.20.3`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that in the https://infura.io site dropdown what I selected was MAINNET instead of RINKEBY which is an ethereum test network.